# String comparison fails

Tags: python, string, comparison

```
output = subprocess.check_output("./mount.sh", shell=True)
print output
if output == "expected_String":
      print "Hurray!"
```

(The print command is just to check if the output is what I expected).The comparison fails everytime and I don't get why. I tried it with this instead of check_output

```
(stdout, stderr) = Popen(["./mount.sh"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()
mountout = stdout
```

but I don't think that's the problem here because

```
 print output
```

gives me what I expect but if I try to compare it to my "expected_String" it is always false.

Comment: it seems that subprocess module don't have a function named `check_output`, is it defined by yourself? If so, please show the code.

Comment: @Charles0429 it's Python2.7 - not in Python2.6 or earlier.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the problem is your output contains additional new line character at the end. You can fix it by calling `.strip()` to remove those:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("./mount.sh", shell=True)
output = output.strip()
```

## Update: How to Find out If a String Ends with New Line?

Consider the following interactive session:

```
>>> s = '''hello\n'''
>>> s.endswith('\n')
True
```

Comment: Thanks alot it was an "invisible" character at the end of the string. output = subprocess.check_output("./mount.sh", shell=True)[:-1] works perfect now. Anyway thanks to all of you

Comment: @user3291061 I tried to use Popen(which generate the expected output in your machine), but there's still new line character at the end.

Comment: Ok is there a way to find out if a string has a new line character? You cant see it when you print it to the console, now I know popen/checkoutput does it but maybe I get something similar later.

Answer (score -1):

For people wondering why this won´t work when reading from an .txt file:
It is no "Newline" but the "EOF" (End of File) Character.

Removing this is possible, but I´m not sure how and if it is advisable.
So instead of

```
if var=="Bread":
```

I wrote

```
if "Bread" in var:
```

Comment: "Bread" in var is not secure, what if var=Breadsmtg? use strip('\n') or a slice var[:-1]